# why my input always take default value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, default-value

here is the code for my learning purpose...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Calculator
{
    abstract class calculator 
    {
        internal abstract int add();
        internal abstract int sub();
        internal abstract int mul();
        internal abstract int div();
        internal abstract double square();
        internal abstract double underroot();

    }
    class mycalculator : calculator
    {
        public mycalculator() :base()
        {
        }
        private int num1, num2;
        public int opr1
        {
            get { return num1; }
            set{num1 = value;}
        }

        public int opr2
        {
            get { return num2; }
            set { num2 = value; }
        }


        internal override int add() {
            return num1 + num2;
        }
        internal override int sub()
        {
            return num2 - num1;
        }
        internal override int mul()
        {
            return num1 * num2;
        }
        internal override int div()
        {
            if(num1 > num2){
            return num1 / num2;
            }else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(num1 + " Must be greater than " + num2 + " and " + num2 + "can not be zero" );
                return 0;
            }
        }
        internal override double square()
        {
            return num1 * num1;
        }
        internal override double underroot()
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(num1);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char choice = 'y';

            while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease Select your Operation....!\n\n\n\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for Addtion\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Subtraction\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for Multiplication\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for Division\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 5 for square\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 6 for UnderRoot\n");
                int opt;
                opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
                mycalculator c = new mycalculator();

                switch (opt)
                {
                    case '1':
                        int a;
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your First Operand");
                        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
                       // a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        c.opr1 = a;
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Second Operand");
                        c.opr2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
                        Console.WriteLine(c.opr1 + " +  " + c.opr2 + "  = " + c.add());
                        break;




                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
                        break;

                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nDo you want to Perform more calculations??\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 'Y' or 'y' to continue, any other key to exit");
                choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
               // Console.WriteLine(choice);



            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

just omitted case for subtraction, multiplication etc for the sake to keep the code less in size...

Problem is :
When I press 1 to add two numbers, It should take first operand and 2nd operand, then, it should show the result... but instead, it shows

```
13 + 10 = 23
```

and if I do for for any other function, say for multiplication it shows

```
13*10 = 130
```

and so on

```
13-10 = 3
```

the Program doesnot ask me to enter values, just shows the result with presumed operand1 as 13, and operand2 as 10....

I never specified anything like that..

can somebody point me from which part of hell these two numbers are Automatically comming???

cursing c# and Visual Studio 2012 right now :(

[image: outPut]

Comment: Learn to debug. Start by setting a breakpoint, pressing F10 and F11 repeatedly and inspecting your variables.

Comment: Just use `ReadLine()` everywhere instead of `Read()`

Comment: Thanks to Everyone for helping me and make me learn the concept correctly... I am new to c# , started learning it right now.. and I am really thankful to you all.. But Issue is, I can only accept One Answer, and I feel that everyone was contributing to make me learn... SO ... Kindly tell me which one to be accepted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define opt as integer.

```
int opt;
opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (opt)
{
    case '1':

 //...
```

You should then within the switch check for integer values:

```
case 1:
// ....
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if I do so, (case 1:) I hit the default :( but if I use (case '1'), then correct part of switch is called....

Comment: Use ReadLine(), because you get the ASCII code by Read(). I update the answer

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that you're typing '1' and then hitting the Enter key. The Enter key sends a carriage return and a newline character to your program. The ASCII codes for those two characters are 13 and 10 respectively. So you are actually entering 13 and 10 even though you're not aware of it.

Comment: Yes I am hitting Enter Key... and if you are right about ASCII values too..if I do not hit the Enter Key, how can I perform my taks??

Comment: Sounds spot on, you don't need to press Enter after pressing 1 as `Console.Read` blocks until a key is pressed. As soon as you press a single key the code resumes, so DONT PRESS ENTER or use `Console.ReadLine` instead

Comment: You could use Console.ReadLine instead of Console.Read. That will read all the characters up to the next CRLF pair. Then you can convert the string you get into a number using String.ToInt32.

Answer (score 1):

In  addition to what @Hans Kilian saied  to correct your example you have to do do the following
change this

```
opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
```

to

```
opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and this

```
case '1':
```

to this

```
case 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

changes you must do:

1. `opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` change to `opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`
2. `case '1':` change to `case 1:` opt is an integer not character
3. `a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` change to `a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`
4. `c.opr2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` change to `c.opr2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

the problem was when you press 1 and hit enter `Console.Read()` reads `\r` (10) and `\n` (13) from input